# This javascript is autoclicking only site url, how can it click a javascript code

Tags: javascript

This is the javascript

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".todoitem").click(function(){
        alert('Item selected');
        window.location = $(this).attr("href");
    });

    $(".todoitem".click();
});

</script>

<div>
    <a href="http://www.google.com" class="todoitem">it is clicking here</a>
</div>
```

I want to put a javascript here instead of `<a href="http://www.google.com" class="todoitem">it is clicking here</a>`

like

`<div> <script type="text/javascript" class="todoitem"></script> </div>`

Comment: Thanks @karthikr that was pretty unreadable

Comment: What you have is good.  What you want is bad practice.  I suggest keeping it how you have it.

Comment: why would u need to do do this?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/XvWhb/

Answer (score 3):

You can't click a script block. You can call a function. Just defined a function and call that from your code, unless I am missing something here.

Comment: Yes, or if what he wants is to write the <a> with JavaScript instead of HTML, then he can just do $(div).append("<a class='todoitem'>Click here.</a>");

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo, make:

```
$(".todoitem".click();
```

this:

```
$(".todoitem").click();
```

or this:

```
$(".todoitem").trigger("click");
```

OR maybe what you are trying to do is using javascript to navigate. If thats the case, try this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.location.href='http://www.google.com'">Going to Google</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you suggesting that you want to write the anchor tag itself as a script instead of HTML?

Try this then:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("<a href='http://www.google.com' class='todoitem'>Click here</a>").appendTo("div");

    $(".todoitem").click(function(){
        alert('Item selected');
        window.location = $(this).attr("href");  //this line is probably unnecessary.  its going to happen because of href click anyway.
    });

    $(".todoitem").click();
});

</script>
```

This will write the todoitem with JS, appending it to "div".  It will then apply the handler and initiate a click and you can leave your HTML as just:

```
<div></div>
```

Comment: But where i will put javascript code

Comment: The JavaScript code should go in the <head> tag of your HTML inside of your document ready handler, just as you have it now.  I added the first line inside of the handler to write the <a> tag.

Comment: See this jsfiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/XvWhb/